# How to create a display mode and edit mode in a Metro App?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

What is the best approach to change TextBlocks to TextBoxes after clicking on Edit button for a Windows 8 Store App? This is something similar to an iOS app that after clicking on an Edit button editable fields become TextBoxes and you can then change data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `TextBlock` just use `TextBox` with `IsReadOnly` property.

on button click mark the `IsReadOnly="True"`

Comment: I think you mean `IsReadOnly` since the textbox doesn't have an `Editable` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [`IsReadOnly` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.isreadonly.aspx).  `IsReadOnly=true;` when you don't want to let them edit the textbox, `IsReadOnly=false;` when you want to let them edit it.